# How to load Image with same url and different image using Glide?

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide library to load images as below

```
public class LoadImageUtils {

private LoadImageUtils() {
    //do nothing
}

private static GenericRequestBuilder<Uri, InputStream, SVG, PictureDrawable> requestBuilder;

public static void loadImage(String avatarUrl, Context context, ImageView personImage) {

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(avatarUrl)) {
        return;
    }

    if (avatarUrl.endsWith(".svg")) {
        initializeRequestBuilder(context);
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(avatarUrl);
        requestBuilder
                .load(uri)
                .into(personImage);
    } else {
        if (context != null) {
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(avatarUrl)
                    .placeholder(R.mipmap.avatar_big)
                    .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
                    .listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(personImage);
        }

    }
}

private static void initializeRequestBuilder(Context context) {
    if (context != null) {
        requestBuilder = Glide.with(context)
                .using(Glide.buildStreamModelLoader(Uri.class, context), InputStream.class)
                .from(Uri.class)
                .as(SVG.class)
                .transcode(new SvgDrawableTranscoder(), PictureDrawable.class)
                .sourceEncoder(new StreamEncoder())
                .cacheDecoder(new FileToStreamDecoder<SVG>(new SvgDecoder()))
                .decoder(new SvgDecoder())
                .placeholder(R.mipmap.avatar_big)
                .error(R.mipmap.avatar_big)
                .animate(android.R.anim.fade_in)
                .listener(new SvgSoftwareLayerSetter<Uri>());
    }
}
```

}

My app is similar to like facebook having **posts, comments to posts, chat functionality**. But whenever users changes their images through web, I am getting same "url" to load the user image. But **Glide** maintains **cache memory to store all the images**.

In my case the previous images are loading because of **same url**.

But If I use `.skipMemoryCache(true)` method, to load all the user images taking so much time.

How can I solve this problem?

> Is there any alternative library which will give better solution than
>   this?

Comment: You should not maintain the cache for this..

Comment: Thanks for quick response. How can I load the images from 2nd time without downloading image from server?

Comment: I am not sure if it will work or not, but try one thing from back-end, when user uploads a new image the boolean at the back-end side is set to true and you'll get it in response. Now at your side you check if that boolean is true you initialise glide without cache and if it is false you can use the image contained in cache.